# Unable to use here() to get to the correct project directory

Tags: r, directory

I have this weird problem. I was able to get here() to work but it stopped working and I can't figure out how to fix it.
So basically the structure of my file is like:
C:/First/Second/Third/Analysis/Scripts
C:/First/Second/Third/Analysis/Data
I want to easily bounce between data and scripts in the code
If I type here("C:/First/")
and then follow up with here(), R says that I'm at
C:/First/Documents

I'm not able to type here("Second", "Third", "Analysis", "Data", "todayscode.R")
because it puts me in the folder:
C:/First/Documents/Second/Third/Analysis/Data/
Which obviously does not exist.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify your working directory before using `here()` . For that you just have to run the following line of code `setwd("C:/First/Second/Third/Analysis/Data")`. In doing so, your working directory will be the `Data` directory.

Comment: My understanding is that here() is about avoiding using setwd commands.... I'm trying to understand how to do it correctly.

Comment: As the help page says you may need to use seed if you change the root of you project subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you say that `C:/First/Documents/Second/Third/Analysis/Data/`  "does not exist". You will need to create a subdirectory if it doesn't exist, but at the beginning of your problem presentation you implied that was an existing directory.

Sounds like you want something like this possibilities:

```
setwd("C:/First/Second/Third/Analysis/")
```

You should first clarify where your version of the `here` function is coming from by typing `here`  at the console input line and noting which namespace it comes from. If you then wanted to refer to a directory with that starting point you could use this (using the example set up in the `here` package at the `here` help page):

```
library(here); library(readr)
readr::read_csv(
  here("data", "penguins.csv"),
  col_types = list(.default = readr::col_guess()),
  n_max = 3
)
```

Comment: I'm saying that C:/First/Documents/Second/Third/Analysis/Data/  "does not exist". because only "C:/First/Second/Third/Analysis/Data/" exits. I ended up creating a .here file in the C:/First folder and then that seems to at least allow me to use the read.csv(here()) command correctly. But I tried putting a .here further on top under the Third folder and that did not work. So it seems like it needs the .here file higher up in the root directory.

Comment: Be careful about file names.  read_csv and read.csv are different. Sorry about not noticing the difference in directory structure. Also take the time to document the package names for functions that are not in the base suite.